# How to turn off automatic operation for Nivo Slider?

Tags: plugins, javascript, slideshow

I am using [Nivo Slider](http://wordpress.org/plugins/nivo-slider-for-wordpress/) plugin to run a slideshow on my site.

It automatically runs a slideshow on top of my screen.  However I want the user to do this *manually* (clicking to advance to the next slide).  How do I turn off the automatic operation?

Comment: There's a big warning that the plugin is being discontinued. And looking at the code, that's a huge spaghetti with really weird stuff on it. I'd stay away...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked [the documentation](http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/#/documentation)? It's right in there, in the **jQuery Plugin Usage** section:

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
    manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
});
```